# IIS 8 issue - how to fix?

Tags: asp.net, iis

**Issue**

> I have a .Net 32bit web application built in VS2008 (compiled for x86
>   CPU), that installs and runs happily on Windows 7 64 bit in a 32 bit
>   application pool.

However if it is installed (using the same installer) on a Windows Server 2012 machine in a 32 bit application pool.
I get an http 500 **error** when I hit the landing page:

> 500.19 overridemodedefault = deny

I suspect an IIS 8 config issue, but can anyone give me some tips on what to look for? Is there some setting that should be in the web.config file, for example, that is not needed for previous versions of IIS?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is aimed at [webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Does this help: http://forums.asp.net/t/1731084.aspx?HTTP+Error+500+19+Internal+Server+Error

Comment: It's aimed at anyone who knows enough about IIS to be able to help with information. I'm sure many in the Stackoverflow community will have that knowledge, even if not actually web administrators.

Comment: I've passed on that link to my collegues in Support. I'll let you know if it works. Thanks for the suggestion.